# UIImage with resizableImage option

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage

I want to set image as a background on my button. So i create an image:

[image: Button]

then I want to implement it as stretchable:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 400)];  
[button setTitle:@"Test Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIImage *buttonImage = [_model.background resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 8, 6, 7)]; //this is screen 1
//UIImage *buttonImage = _model.background; //this is screen 2   

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];        
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self addSubview:button];
```

I want to background stretch like in screen 2 but corners will sharp like screen 1. _model.background is UIImage contains original button background from the top of this post.

[image: Screen 1] [image: Screen 2]

Am I using it right? I follow the documentation so `UIEdgeInsetsMake(top,left,bottom,right)` should be unstreachable corners, right?

Comment: UIImage. My original button: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xO3DT.png

Comment: Are you using 9-patch format ? And one more thing to make it clear, you can not have screen 2 ?

Comment: Yes, this is file 9.png. But i'm not using any third party frameworks to read it. This is a problem?

Comment: And screen 2 have very VERY ugly corners. This is unacceptable for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, the part inside the insets (the part not locked via cap settings) is *tiled*.  So you should have a small 1 pixel region to tile.  E.g. make the insets be `UIEdgeIndetsMake(20,8,19,7)`

This produces:

[image]

Comment: If you want the inside part to be a gradient, and not a single color tiled all the way through, then maybe check out some examples (search stack overflow / google) of how to draw gradients on buttons by adding a CALayer.

Answer (score 1):

honestly, this is not the best picture for this effect but, please, try this line:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.f, 62.f, 20.f, 62.f)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```